# Sending an email with buttons inside it using nodemailer

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

I've made a function that send an Email to people who is registered in my site to confirm their data, it works just fine, I send a simple plain text saying something like "Hey, this is your data {data}, is that correct?" and a link below it to confirm it or not but I don't like the way a link looks like, I'd like to make it cuter by using buttons instead those links, there's anyway to do it?

```
    function sendEmail(user) {
      const mailOptions = {
        from: `${APP_NAME} `,
        to: paciente.correo,
      };

      mailOptions.subject = user.name+ `, confirm your data`;
      mailOptions.text = 'Hi ' + user.name+ ', is this data correct?\n ' + user.data +  '. Click the following link to confirm it \n' + confirmationLinkGen (user);

      return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions).then(() => {
        return console.log('Mail sent to:', user.email);
      }).catch(error => {
         return console.log(error);
      });
    }
```

I took a random image from Google that uses a button to redirect people from the email to somewhere, I'd like my email content to look something like that

https://pepipost.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/zapier_cta.png

Comment: To style like that, you need html. You can find some good tutorial for sending html emails in Node.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use htmls in your nodemailer transport as following,

```
mailOptions.html = '<b>Hello world?</b>'
```

But on a additional note, please mind that most javascript would be blocked by mail receivers such as gmail to provide better security.